# How to instantiate a "hidden" UIView in a Storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift

Whenever I have a scenario that involves repeating UIViews, like, views in a UIScrollView, I have resorted to creating a `.xib` file, then `Bundle.instantiateViewController(...)` (or whatever) from the `UIViewController` that owns the `UIScrollView`.

I found another way (or thought I did!) that involves putting the `UIView` *above* the `UIViewController`, i.e. above the ribbon, inside the Storyboard. So I have something like the following:

[image: UIView above the ribbon in a Storyboard]

Next, I assigned a custom class to this `UIView` and thought I could just instantiate it in code. It didn't work as it seems to be a plain `UIView` albeit subclassed. I guess I'd need to go via `UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController` but then I instantiate the whole thing again, which I don't want. I just want my custom UIView.

**My question is: Is the .xib approach the way to go, or what am I missing with the Storyboard approach?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create an IBOutlet of that view in the ViewController and you can then use it.

But if you need to reuse your view then you'll need to create a xib for it. There is no other way to reuse view

Comment: I want to duplicate the UIView several times.

Comment: Then you will need to create a xib for it and then use it. There is no other way to only use the View again and again

Comment: I'll accept your answer if you add that to your answer.

Comment: Edited my answer 